How to investigate variable importance when using bart_machine_Arr and get a list of bartmachine objects?
For a single bartmachine object, we can use function investigate_var_importance to get a variable importance outcome. However, even using the num_replicates_for_avg statement in the function, the outcome is still unstable.
We have bartMachineArr(bart_machine, R=5) function which can allow us to compute five bartmachines and get a stable average. But I do not think that investigate_var_importance function can be applied on the outcome of bartMachineArr, since it's a list of bartmachine objects. Here is the error of implementing these two together:


investigate_var_importance(bart_machine_Arr, num_replicates_for_avg = 20)
Error in check_serialization(bart_machine) :
This bartMachine object was loaded from an R image but was not serialized.
Please build bartMachine using the option "serialize = TRUE" next time.


Therefore, I am wondering if there is any possible way to investigate the variable importance on a more stable bartmachine outcome? Thank you very much!
